# segfault during freeing memory in a linked-list(queue) by a thread

Tags: multithreading, segmentation-fault, free

I have created a thread. The main function is creating an element and appending it to the Tail/End of a queue. The thread is reading the list from Head/Start and is releasing the memory after.

I have the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

typedef struct stCheckFree
{
    char name[30];
    int doneflag;
    struct stCheckFree *next;
}CheckFree;

CheckFree *gHead=NULL;
CheckFree *gTail=NULL;

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    char *message1 = "Thread 1";
    int iret1;
    unsigned long TestCount=1;

    CheckFree *pCurr=NULL;
    CheckFree *pTemp=NULL;

    iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);

    while(1)
    {
        pCurr=malloc(sizeof(CheckFree));
        memset(pCurr,0,sizeof(CheckFree));

        printf("Malloc\n");
        sprintf(pCurr->name,"Test-%ld",TestCount); TestCount++;
        pCurr->doneflag=0;
        pCurr->next=NULL;

        pTemp=gTail;
        gTail=pCurr;
        if(pTemp) pTemp->next=gTail;

        if(!gHead)
        {
            gHead=gTail;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
    CheckFree *pTrav;

    while(1)
    {
        pTrav=gHead;
        if(pTrav)
        {
            printf("[%s]\n",pTrav->name);
            pTrav->doneflag=1;

            gHead=gHead->next;
            free(pTrav);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code its giving me a segfault. What might be the issue?
Please help!

Thanks.

PS- If i remove the free(), its running splendidly!!!

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**---EDIT 1---**
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I am not sure if this is the fix, but I need more inputs from other **stackoverflow** members.

```
void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
    CheckFree *pTrav;

    while(1)
    {
        pTrav=gHead;
        if(pTrav)
        {
            printf("[%s]\n",pTrav->name);
            pTrav->doneflag=1;

            gHead=gHead->next;

            if(!gHead) gTail=NULL;                /* NEW CODE */

            free(pTrav);
            sleep(0.7);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help as it is important! :)
Thanks again.

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**---EDIT 2---**
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

The code change:- 
    if(!gHead) gTail=NULL;                /* NEW CODE */
is destroying data by re-initializing NULL over it.

You can see it by just doing the following code changes:

> ...
> pTemp=gTail;
>       gTail=pCurr;
>       if(pTemp) pTemp->next=gTail;
>       if(!gTail)printf("Data lost\n");
>       if(!gHead)
>       {
> ...

Please help me to rectify this issue...

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**---EDIT 3---**
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
Following @wazy's recommendation of using mutex lock I updated the code as follows:-

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void * thread_function( void *ptr );

typedef struct stCheckFree
{
    char name[30];
    int doneflag;
    struct stCheckFree *next;
}CheckFree;

pthread_mutex_t lock;    // EDIT 3

CheckFree *gHead=NULL;
CheckFree *gTail=NULL;

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    char *message1 = "Thread 1";
    int  iret1;
    unsigned long TestCount=1;

    CheckFree *pCurr=NULL;
    CheckFree *pTemp=NULL;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)    // EDIT 3
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL,  thread_function, (void*) message1);

    while(1)
    {
        pCurr=malloc(sizeof(CheckFree));
        memset(pCurr,0,sizeof(CheckFree));

        sprintf(pCurr->name,"Test-%ld",TestCount); TestCount++;
        pCurr->doneflag=0;
        pCurr->next=NULL;

        pTemp=gTail;
        gTail=pCurr;
        if(pTemp) pTemp->next=gTail;


        //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);    // EDIT 3(commented out)
        if(!gHead)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);    // EDIT 4
            gHead=gTail;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);    // EDIT 4
        }
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);    // EDIT 3(commented out)
    }

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);

    return 0;
}

void * thread_function( void *ptr )
{
    CheckFree *pTrav;

    while(1)
    {
        pTrav=gHead;
        if(pTrav)
        {
            //printf("[%s]\n",pTrav->name);
            pTrav->doneflag=1;

            gHead=gHead->next;
            if(!gHead) sleep(1);//gTail=NULL;
            free(pTrav);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track????? 
Thanks!!!

Comment: The new line solved the crashing, but its creating another bug. Due to that line I am loosing data.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code gives me double free or corruption (fasttop) from glibc. Looking at your code I see that you are using both gHead in your thread1 and in your main thread. It seems to be a multithreading synchronization problem.

Comment: Yes! exactly!!! Could you please direct me to a correct bug free happy place, where i can malloc and free!!! Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Please search the term mutex.

Comment: Hi @wazy, please refer to my "EDIT 3" above. Please comment on the code changes. :)

Comment: That doesn't segment fault anymore (ran it to 100k tests). Do you understand why? Also what are your concerns at this point?

Comment: I have to analyse. Also, when I am running top cmd, my cpu usage is showing 120-160% and 300MiB Memory!!! I don't know why is it so high for this small code snippet!!! :-/

Comment: First of all, is your intent to loop this infintely?

Comment: well, this code is just a very short version on what i am working on. I created this dummy code to analyse the bug. To answer your question, yes I "need" to run this in infinite loop!

Comment: Constantly locking and unlocking a mutex is very expensive and will definitely cause that overhead. Another serious concern is if you run this in valgrind you will see you have very bad memory leaks. Unfortunately I do not have time to propose changes for you at this point.

Comment: I modified the code so that the control will break out after 10,000,000 iterations from both the infinite while loops. Before termination Valgrind is saying 10,000,000 blocks malloc'ed and free'ed. Also I moved the mutex_locked and mutex_unlock within the if condition(See Edit4). So I suppose the locking and unlocking wont happen so often.